# TestCafe - How to check if the value is greater than or equal in the assertion

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I would like to check the value which appears in below selector if it is greater than or equal to 1

```html
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-white"> 0 </span>
```

(In steps, the value "0" should change into "1" or "2"..)

I defined this selector in common.js

```js
this.pill = Selector('[class*=badge-white]');
```

and wrote the following assertion:

```js
await t.expect((common.pill).innerText).gte(1);
```

I received the following error: " AssertionError: expected '1' to be a number or a date'. I do not know how to convert ((common.pill).innerText) to number? I tried sth like this:

```js
await t.expect(Number((common.pill).innerText)).gte(1);
```

But it does not work.
When I check if the value is deep equal eg."3"i write:

```js
await t.expect((common.pill).innerText).eql('3');
```

And it works.
Could anybody help me how to check value greater than or equal?
I studied it thoroughly but I can't find a solution https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/assert.html :(

I found a solution when created const

```js
const number = await common.pill.innerText;

await t.expect(Number(number)).gte(1);
```

It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

so my question is why below code did not work

```js
await t.expect(Number((common.pill).innerText)).gte(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
await t.expect(Number((common.pill).innerText)).gte(1);
```

does not work because ‘Number’ does not expect unresolved promises, so yes, you need to do this as follows:

```
const number = await common.pill.innerText;
await t.expect(Number(number)).gte(1);
```

This code

```
await t.expect((common.pill).innerText).eql('3');
```

works because ’expect’ supports awaiting promises automatically.